# Show that $N_p^p (f+g) \le N_p^p(f) + N_p^p (g)$ for $p\in ]0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, normed-spaces

Let $p\in ]0,1]$ and $f,g$ be two measurable functions. For $l\in \Bbb R, l\gt 0$ and a measurable function $k$, $N_l (k)$ is defined as follows:
$$N_l(k) := (\int_X \mid k\mid ^l d\mu)^{1/l}$$

Now I have to show the following two properties of $N$:

1. $N_p^p (f+g) \le N_p^p(f) + N_p^p (g)$
2. $N_p(f+g)\le 2^{\frac{1}{p} -1} (N_p(f)+N_p(g))$

Any tipps or ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you sure that $l>0$ instead of $l\geq 1$? since for your first question this would be the minkowski inequality in that case.

Comment: yes i know, but p has to be between 0 and 1. We've already proven the minkowski inequality, i.e. the case for p larger that 1

Comment: what I can tell is that (at least for the first case) it would be enough to show that for simple functions, e.g. the case w.l.o.g. $k=\mathrm{const}$.

Comment: seems like there is all you need: https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/lp-spaces-for-p-in-01.pdf